# How file manipulations perform during power outage

Tags: java, linux, operating-system, filesystems

**Linux machine, Java standalone application**

I am having the following situation:

I have: 
consecutive file write(which creates the destination file and writes some content to it) and file move.

I also have a power outage problem, which instantly cuts off the power of computer during these operations.

**As a result**, I am getting that the **file was created, and it was moved as well, but the file content is empty.**

The question is what under the hood can be causing this exact outcome? Considering the time sensitivity, may be hard drive is disabled before the processor and RAM during the cut out, but in that case, how is it possible that the file is created and moved after, but the write before moving is not successful?

I tried catching and logging the exception and debug information but the problem is power outage disables the logging abilities(I/O) as well.

```
try {
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, JsonUtils.toJson(object));
} finally {
    if (file.exists()) {
        FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(file, new File(path), true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Linux file systems don't necessarily write things to disk immediately, or in exactly the order that you wrote them.  That includes both file content and file / directory metadata.

So if you get a power failure at the wrong time, you may find that the file data and metadata is inconsistent.

Normally this doesn't matter.  (If the power fails and you don't have a UPS, the applications go away without getting a chance to finish what they were doing.)

However, if it does matter, you can do the following: to force the file to "sync" before you move it:

```
   FileOutputStream fos = ...

   // write to file

   fs.getFD().sync();
   fs.close();

   // now move it
```

You need to read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html#sync()) for `sync()` carefully to understand what the method actually does.

You also need to read the javadoc for the method you are using to move the file regarding atomicity.